# Code First, how to set a foreign key as primary key and the relation?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, mapping, code-first

This is the diagram relation in picture.

[image]

I know this mapping is bad, but how must be right?

```
HasKey(x => x.CuentaId).HasRequired(x => x.Cuenta).WithRequiredDependent().Map(x=>x.MapKey("CuentaId"))
```

or is it ok if I remove Haskey like this?

```
HasRequired(x => x.Cuenta).WithRequiredDependent().Map(x=>x.MapKey("CuentaId"))
```

but then how can Entity know what is the primary key?

Comment: `HasKey(x => x.CuentaId).HasRequired(x => x.Cuenta).WithRequiredDependent()` should be enough.

Comment: yes it was but I did it in two lines  HasKey(x => x.CuentaId);

            HasRequired(x => x.Cuenta).WithRequiredDependent();

Comment: HasKey, even if followed by other statements, sets the PK of the entity. What exactly is your problem, what error occured?